# Subderivative of $ ||Au||_{L^{\infty}} $ to Compute Proximal Operator / Prox Operator

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, banach-spaces, proximal-operators, non-smooth-analysis

I am looking for ways to compute the subderivative of $  ||Au||_{L^{\infty}} $, as I want to solve the minimization problem of
\begin{equation} \min\limits_u \quad \lambda ||Au||_{L^{\infty}} + \frac{1}{2} || u - f ||^2_{L^{2}} \quad.
\end{equation}

However I have no idea where to start. I tried looking at the Gateaux derivative to get an intuition on the subdifferential, but I am not even certain how the derivative interacts with the esssup of the norm.

After Boyd-Vanderbergh, there should exist a unique prox. operator for the min-problem. I am fammiliar with the procedure for subdiff/prox operator for $L^1$ and $L^2$, yet how do I deal with the $esssup$ ?

P.S: A similar question has already been asked here: [proximal operator of infinity norm](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/527872/proximal-operator-of-infinity-norm), but I am fairly certain that this is wrong as $L^1$ is not dual to $L^\infty$.

Comment: The linked question is fine, though as a commenter points out it could use more development. But it will not help you here anyway, because the presence of $A$ changes things irretrievably.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, the problem has a unique solution (by strong convexity of the objective), but you can't compute it closed-form...

Let's concentrate on your "real" problem: computing the subdifferential of that composite term. To this end, define $g = \|.\|_\infty$ and $f := g \circ A$. By basic properties of subdifferentials, it's clear that
\begin{equation}
\partial f(u) = A^T\partial g(Au) := \{A^Tv | v \in \partial \|Au\|_\infty\}.
\end{equation}
So it suffices to compute the subdifferential of the $\infty$-norm.

Now, for any $z$, $g(z) = \|z\|_\infty = \underset{\|w\|_1 \le 1}{\sup}z^Tw$, and so by the Danskin-Bertsekas Theorem for subdifferentials (Proposition A.22 of the PhD thesis of Bertsekas), it holds that
\begin{equation}\partial \|z\|_\infty = \mathrm{conv}\{w\text{ s.t } \|w\|_1 \le 1, z^Tw = \|z\|_\infty\} = \{w\text{ s.t } \|w\|_1 \le 1, z^Tw = \|z\|_\infty\}.
\end{equation}
Putting things together, we have $\partial f(u) = \{A^Tw \text{ s.t } \|w\|_1 \le 1, w^TAu = \|Au\|_\infty\}$.

Comment: thank you for the answer, although as it is an interesting result it seems like I just traded my minimization problem for a slightly different one as I now have to solve
\begin{equation}
w = argmax_{||w||_1 =1} <w,Au> \quad ,
\end{equation} with the extra information that $max_{||w||_1 =1} <w,Au> = || Au||_\infty $

Comment: Also thank you for pointing out  the Danskin-Bertsekas theorem :)
Maybe the formulating the norm derivative by its predual supremum is too general ? I guess I will have to think about this for a while.

Comment: I'm afraid you'll have to solve your (original) problem iteratively. Lookup ADMM, primal-dual algorithm (of chambolle-pock), etc. These are all go-to methods for solving such problems with composite sums. Also, If you can post your complete problem here (not just the prox-computation part), then I can give you more explicit hints which will be more adapted to your total problem.

Comment: Yes, I ended up computing an ADMM algorithm.

Comment: In $\mathbb R^n$, the $\ell_\infty$ unit-ball is a cartesian product of $n$ identical pieces, namely $\mathbb B_\infty = [-1, 1]^n$. Thus $\text{proj}_{\mathbb B_\infty}(u) = (\text{proj}_{[-1, 1]}(u_j))_{j=1,\ldots, n}$. **Exercise:** Derive a formula for projection onto a compact 1D interval $[a, b]$. You're done.

Comment: I would add that specifically it is $ \operatorname{sign} \left( {z}_{j} \right) \boldsymbol{e}_{j} $ where $ j = \arg \min_{i} \left| {z}_{i} \right| $ and $ \boldsymbol{e}_{j} $ is the $ j $ -th standard basis.