# Dual of the Primal Problem: $\min_{x} \left\|x - a \right\|_2^2 \ \text{s.t.} \ \|x \|_{\infty} \leq b$: Projection to the $ {L}_{\infty} $ Ball

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, optimization, convex-analysis, convex-optimization

I am looking for the dual of the following optimization problem

\begin{alignat}{2}
\tag{P1}
&\underset{x \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times 1}}{\text{minimize}}&\quad \frac{1}{2}\left\|x - a \right\|_2^2\\ 
&\text{subject to }&\quad \|x\|_{\infty} \leq b, 
\end{alignat}
where $a \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times 1}$ and $b \in \mathbb{R}_{\geq0}$.

**Question**:

> How to find the dual of this problem ${\text{P}}1$ (in particular, unconstrained problem by using the dual of the infinity norm ball)?

---

Partial understanding (perhaps I should say everything is mixed up in my head):

As I understand so far, the dual norm of the inifinity norm ball is $\ell_1$ norm, that is,
$\|x\|_1 = \underset{\|z \|_{\infty} \leq 1}{\max} z^Tx$. My "problem" is how to remove the constraint in the primal problem ${\text{P}}1$ and convert the problem as unconstrained by using the fact there is an equivalent notion of dual norm. Can anybody help me please?

Comment: The solution is given by [Orthogonal Projection onto the $ {L}_{\infty} $ Unit Ball](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1825747). Though this is a direct solution, not through the dual formulation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let the Lagrangian be:
$$L(\mathbf{x};\lambda,\mathbf{\mu})=\frac{1}{2}\|\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{a}\|_2^2+\mathbf{\lambda}^T(\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{b})-\mathbf{\mu}^T(\mathbf{x}+\mathbf{b}),$$
where $\lambda,\mu\in \mathbb{R}^n_+$ and $\mathbf{b}=(b,b,\dots,b)$ is an $n$-long vector with all components equal to $b$. What we did is to convert the constraint $\|\mathbf{x}\|_{\infty}\leq b$ to separable linear constraints $-b\leq x_i\leq b$. The gradient of $L$ will be $$\nabla_x L = \mathbf{x}-\mathbf{a} +\lambda -\mu \overset{\nabla_x L=\mathbf{0}}{\longrightarrow}\mathbf{x}^*=\mathbf{a}-\lambda+\mu.$$
Overall we have $$L(\mathbf{x}^*;\lambda,\mathbf{\mu})=q(\lambda,\mu)=\frac{1}{2}\|\mu-\lambda\|^2+\lambda^T(\mathbf{a}+\mu-\lambda-\mathbf{b})-\mu^T(\mathbf{a}+\mu-\lambda+\mathbf{b})=\\ -\frac{1}{2}\|\mu-\lambda\|^2-\mathbf{a}^T(\mu-\lambda)-\mathbf{b}^T(\mu+\lambda)$$ and your dual problem is $$\max_{\lambda,\mu\in\mathbb{R}^n_+}q(\lambda,\mu).$$

Not the most appealing dual problem I have to admit. We moved from a one variable problem to two variables, and for iterative methods - projecting onto the $l_{\infty}$ ball is a easy as projecting onto $\mathbb{R}^n_+$. Duality comes in handy if we were able to get a problem of lower dimension or a "better" constraint set, which is not the case in hand.

Comment: Thank you for your reply (+1). I agree that this dual is not appealing. On one hand, the projection approach can be considered as well. On the other hand, I was wondering if it is possible to convert the $\ell_{\infty}$ ball to $\ell_1$ (which can make the problem unconstrained).

Comment: @learning first of all, I now notice that the dual problem is exactly like to primal problem. Have a good look and you'll see why. Secondly, converting a constrained problem to an unconstrained one is what we did when constructing the Lagrangian. Then the problem is converted from having just $\mathbf{x}$ as variable to having  $\mathbf{x,\lambda}$. If you're looking to get an explicit solution to the problem, unfortunately that's not possible. You need an iterative method, and luckily, the problem **P1** you presented is very easily and efficiently solved using first or second order methods.

Comment: @learning As mentioned before, we generally use duality when it allows us to cast the problem in a way that is easier to handle by an algorithmic framework, or if it reduces the dimension of the problem. Since complexity is mostly dependent on dimension, this can provide a substantial improvement in performance. However, in your case it doesn't happen since: 1) it's easy to begin with 2) the constraint set has a dimension equal to the problem dimension, as these are box constraints (there is a separable constraint for each variable). Therefore the dual problem is of the same dimension

Comment: Thank you for your reply. With respect to your first comment. Indeed, both primal and dual problems are similar. I agree with your comments.

Comment: I might be missing something, but the above seems like Projection onto the $ {L}_{\infty} $ Ball. This solved in https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1825772. What am I missing? There is no need for First Order Methods, there is a closed form solution.