# Proof for the orthogonal projection onto the L-infinity $L_{\infty}$ norm ball for the complex-valued

Tags: complex-analysis, optimization, convex-analysis, convex-optimization, proximal-operators

> Problem: Prove orthogonal projection onto the $L_{\infty}$ norm ball, for $x \in \mathbb{C}^N$ and $\eta \geq 0$, is

\begin{align}
P_{B_{\| \cdot \|_{\infty} \leq \eta}} 
&= \left[\operatorname{sign}(x_n) \min\left\{ |x_n|, \eta \right\} \right]_{1\leq n \leq N} \\ 
&= \left[\left(\frac{x_n}{|x_n|}\right) \min\left\{ |x_n|, \eta \right\} \right]_{1\leq n \leq N}   .
\end{align}

The source of the above result is here http://proximity-operator.net/indicatorfunctions.html. However, there is no reference. So, I wonder how it is proved for the complex-valued. There are some posts that prove orthogonal projection onto the $L_{\infty}$ norm ball for the *real-valued data*, e.g., [Orthogonal Projection onto the $ {L}_{\infty} $ Unit Ball](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1825747/orthogonal-projection-onto-the-l-infty-unit-ball). **Does any expert know how to prove it for the complex-valued?** Thank you so much in advance.