# Proximal Operator of an $ {L}_{\infty} $ Norm with a Constraint

Tags: optimization, convex-analysis, convex-optimization, proximal-operators

Dear Convex Optimization Experts,

My question is related to this post: [The Proximal Operator of the $ {L}_{\infty} $ (Infinity Norm)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/527872/the-proximal-operator-of-the-l-infty-infinity-norm), but not really same, I think, as I have a constraint. Apologies if it is obvious to extend the answer.

So, I am seeking a proximal operator $\textrm{prox}_{\lambda f}(x)$ of this function $$f(x) = I\left\{x \in C \right\} \ ,$$ $$C = \left\{x : \lVert x \rVert_{\infty} \leq \gamma \right\} \ ,$$
where $x \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times 1}$, $I\left\{\cdot \right\}$ is an indicator/characteristic function, $\gamma \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times 1}$, and the constraint $\lVert x \rVert_{\infty} \leq \gamma$ is element-wise.

EDIT: The desired constraint is:
$$C = \left\{x : |x_i| \leq \gamma_i \right\} \ ,$$

Comment: $\| x \|_{\infty}$ is a scalar, so $\gamma$ should be a scalar too.

Comment: The prox operator for the indicator function of a convex set is simply the projection onto the set $C$.  Algorithms for the projection onto your particular set $C$ are well known.

Comment: It is an element-wise operation. Example, if I have a vector $x = [1, 2, 3, 2, 4] $ and $\gamma = [3, 3, 3, 3, 3] $ of course, for simplicity, I can consider a constant $\gamma$.  Does that make sense?

Comment: You're constraint would then be $| x_{i} | \leq \gamma_{i}$ for $i=1, 2, \ldots, n$.  The projection onto this box is also very simple to compute.

Comment: @user550103 wrote "Does that make sense?"  No, it doesn't. $\|x\|_\infty = 4$ for your sample $x$.

Comment: @Brian: thanks for that. Yes, this is what I want to do actually.

Comment: @BrianBorchers: May I know the projection onto such box please?